# xsl-fo image size inside table

Tags: xsl-fo

I want to put an image inside a table cell. If the image is too large, it will vertically spill out beyond the page limits.

Here is my code snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:mb="http://www.m-box.at">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4-landscape" page-height="21cm" page-width="29.7cm" margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom="1cm" margin-left="1cm" margin-right="1cm">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="1.5cm" margin-bottom="1.5cm"/>
            <fo:region-before extent="1.5cm"/>
            <fo:region-after extent="1.5cm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-landscape">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
            <fo:block text-align="right" border-top-width="1px" border-top-style="solid" padding-top="1mm">
                        page
                <fo:page-number/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="collapse" margin-top="2mm" margin-bottom="2mm">
                <fo:table-column column-width="20%" border-right="solid 1pt #000000"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="80%"/>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block/>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell padding-left="2mm">
                            <fo:block font-family="Arial, MS Gothic">
                                <fo:external-graphic src="file:C:/temp/1234.jpg" content-width="scale-down-to-fit" content-height="scale-down-to-fit" width="100%" height="100%"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

I've tried different things, for instance leaving out the specs about the height. No success though.
If I specify an absolute value for the height (100mm instead of 100%) the image is scaled down properly. This is not practical though because first of all this means that the space specified (the 100mm or whatever) is being used, even if the image is smaller.

Here's a screenshot of the wrong output:
[image]

The horizontal line at the bottom is actually already part of the page footer (xsl-region-after). The image shouldn't extend beyond that line.

Comment: A table row that doesn't fit on the current page would normally just be moved to the next page.  Have you set any properties that force the table cell to stay on the current page?

Comment: The fo:block with the external graphic has the property keep-with-next.within-page="always"  - but I already experimented with leaving this away, no success.

Comment: The problem, I think, comes from the fact that the image, if itd width is scaled to fill the horizontally available space, is too high to fit onto the page. And then it uses up all the space in the region-body, ignoring the margin-bottom. That's what I guess.

Comment: You don't show `keep-with-next.within-page="always"` in your code sample.  Can you increase your code sample to accurately show the whole `fo:table-row`?  Is the horizontal line at the top at the top of the `fo:region-body` area?

Comment: I left the details out because I had experimented with and without such settings and, I wanted to keep the code sample small. Anyway, I edited my post and now included the full code needed to reproduce the problem. The 1234.jpg is 800 x 600 pixels. I run this fo through FOP 2.2. It looks like the width is winning over the height. Is there a way to shrink the image to the viewport both in terms of width and height?

Comment: Sorry, but the images scales for me using AH Formatter V6.5 with your updated FO, even with a 2,400 x 2,400 pixel image.  The way that I could get something like your result was by removing the `width` and `height` properties.  You could try setting `max-height` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#max-height) to a length and using it on one or more of the `fo:external-graphic`, `fo:block`, `fo:table-cell`, and `fo:table-row` but, as I said, it already works for me.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it's a FOP issue then. Further tests suggest that FOP does not observe the bottom margin of region-body and max-width wins over height. Now I'm working around that by specifying max-height with an absolute value. Not nice, but working. I'll try to file a bug report.